# zero value for all types?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, zero

In C++11, is there a way to initialize a value to zero for arithmetic and class types (with absolutely no overhead at running time for the arithmetic types) ?

```
template<typename T> void myFunction(T& x)
{
    x = 0; // How to make this works for T = double but also for T = std::string ?
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is not initialization, it's assignment. Do you actually want to do *this* or real initialization?

Comment: Yes I want to assign the default value (0 for arithmetic types, default constructor for others that have copy+assignment operator)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the default constructor to "clear" a variable:

```
template<class T>
void clear(T &v)
{
    v = T();
}
```

This will work for all primitive types, pointers and types that has a default constructor *and* an assignment operator (which all classes will have by default, unless told not to, or they are made protected/private).

Comment: Furthermore, this also works for all primitive types too (such as `int` and `int*`) even though they do not have neither a constructor nor an assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

`x = {};` is the natural assignment counterpart to `T t = {};`/`T t {}`, which itself is the natural way to obtain an initialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a class to zero with `= 0;` may have no sense for some classes, unless they've defined the `=` operator.

If you ever only called pointers and simple types, it could work (`T` would only be: `int`, `double`, `myClass*`, `myClassB*`).

Answer (score 0):

Your criterias are not possible in classical C++. None of the answers will totally work. Since `TYPE t()` and `TYPE t {}` both call the default constructor. Thus, if there is no default constructor, then there will be a compile failure.

You will have to do something like `ZeroMemory`.

But keep in mind that default constructors are run at run-time anyhow.